# Google Cloud Function and Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts

I want to access Youtube Content Owner API with Google Cloud Functions. For that the service account used by GCF has to have access to that API.

When I create a Google Cloud Function, it's automatically assigned a service account. In this case the "App Engine default service account". I have a few questions about this.

1. Does Google Cloud Function always use "App Engine default service account" as the service account?
2. While editing the cloud function, I cannot see any way to change a service account of a Google Cloud Function. Once it is set up for a Cloud Function, the service account can not be changed, right?
3. If the default service account is given access to Youtube Content Owner API then Google Cloud Functions will have it, too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, Cloud Functions use the App Engine default service account, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/services#using_services_with_cloud_functions).
2. Indeed there is no such option yet. There is a public [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63801748) opened for this if you are interested.
3. True, Cloud Function will inherit all the access right from [the default service account](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/services#using_services_with_cloud_functions).

Alternatively, to use credentials with Cloud Functions other then the App Engine Default service account you could:

- use an [authentication token](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/authentication-in-http-cloud-functions)
- upload a non-default service account directly with your Cloud Function and use it from with in it as described [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail)

Comment: How do you actually use the default service account though? I am trying to access gmail. I am having to do the following, and using a json file of the default service account credentials. I can't find a way to not have to upload this file...

`credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject("my.email@email.com")
    
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials, cache_discovery=False)`

Comment: @BrainPermafrost Hi, Did you find the answer for this? Mine is exactly the same requirement. Please let me know.

Comment: @SharathKirani Unfortunately no, I have not found a way around it. I am still having to upload the service account file. In my use case, I need to access google sheets from our GCP project (from a Cloud Function).  To solve this, I am now moving from google sheets to airtable. Once I complete this move, I will no longer need to access google sheets and, therefore, will not longer have to deal with this issue.

Comment: @SharathKirani Having said the above, if we had to keep using google sheets, I would make a service account specifically for this purpose, I would then store the service account json file in Google Secret Manager. A cloud function can access this and then use the file to connect to google sheets/drive.  This way you the json file will not be part of the Cloud Function files, but stored in Google Secret Manager. I have used this method for a Cloud Function that needs to access an ssh keys. The pem and/or pub files are stored in Google Secret Manager and a cloud function is able to access them.

Comment: @BrainPermafrost Very true, even i was also planning to use secret manager. Thanks for the response. I am using admin api instead you are using gmail.

Comment: Just a quick update: Option 2 is implemented.