# Getting google.oauth2 credentials from attached service account in a Google Cloud function using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth, gmail-api, service-accounts

I am writing a Google Cloud function and I want to use the `google.oauth2.service_account.with_subject()` function to impersonate a user to access their gmail inbox, but I am unable to find a way to use the attached service account to obtain the oauth2 credentials to run it.

[In the docs](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide.html), it recommends using the `google.auth.default()` function to obtain credentials, but these credentials cannot be used to run the `google.oauth2.service_account.with_subject()` function. The best workaround I could come up with is to use oauth2 credentials to get the service accounts json key file and use secrets / environmental variables to load it into the function. This seems messy especially when `google.auth.default()` shows how something so similar can be done in a one liner.

Considering how little I can find on what I am trying to do makes me think I am approaching this wrong, so I would appreciate any suggestions to approach this problem differently.

As I was writing this, I was recommended a [single post and discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50133390/21817668) talking about this. They seemed to come to the same workaround as me, but maybe there is a better workaround (the post also doesn't answer my question, because I am specifically looking for a way to grab oauth2 credentials from the attached service account to a Cloud Function, NOT just load in any credentials).

The service account has been granted Domain Wide Delegation of Authority and the user account is part of the same domain. Furthermore, the function is successfully called and run with the service account attached. The only api that is being used is the gmail API, specifically the 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly' scope which has been granted to the service account and is passed to the credentials object in the code.

Here is some code context for what I want, this code does not run.

```py
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def process_message(cloud_event):
  """Entrypoint for Google Cloud Function."""

  SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

  # Loading the service account credentials using google.auth
  # Ideally would be google.oauth2.default(scopes=SCOPES), but that doesn't exist
  credentials, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)
  
  # DOES NOT WORK since this function doesn't exist for google.auth
  # and requires google.oauth2 credentials
  delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(user_email)

  # Fetch inbox of gmail user in our domain
  service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
  results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()

  return results
```

I originally tried to use this code:

```py
source_credentials.refresh(requests.Request())
print("Source Credentials:", source_credentials)
target_credentials = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
  source_credentials=source_credentials,
  target_principal='<user@domain>',
  target_scopes = SCOPES,
  lifetime=500
  )
```

But I would get this error:
`google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials', '{\n "error": {\n "code": 404,\n "message": "Not found; Gaia id not found for email <user@domain>",\n "status": "NOT_FOUND"\n }\n}\n')`

I tried to find more information on this but was struggling to find any exact hits for it when searching the error. So that is why I am trying to use the `with_subject()` function

Comment: You can only use a service account to impersonate a user if a) the user is part of Google Workspace and b) you have enabled Domain Wide Delegation of Authority and c) the service account that you created needs to be granted access by a super administrator for the domain. Edit your post with more details on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the wrong type (class) of a credentials object. Instead, you must use the `service_account` class.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH,
        scopes=SCOPES)

delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(user_email)
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it very clear, I am aware that that is the correct way to grab the oauth2 credentials. However, I would  like to run it in a Google Cloud function and don't want to use secrets to store the account file (it is the work around I will do, but I feel like there has to be a better way). I have edited my response with some more context.

Comment: You wrote a comment and then deleted that had a direction I originally tried, so I added some context for that too. I actually think using the `impersonated_credentials` command is the right way to go, but I will need to look into the error more. I don't mean to waste your time and I will look into it more on my own later.

Comment: @user21817668 The type of credential class that is created depends on how ADC is set up. One of the important items is that not all credential methods provide the **private key**. This method will not always work `google.auth.default()`. I deleted my comment and instead posted the correct answer for Domain Wide Delegation of Authority for a service account.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you test the code?
This bit:

```
source_credentials.refresh(requests.Request())
```

did not work on my local machine. It only worked for me when I deployed the function to Cloud Functions and curled it from a Compute Instance.

I followed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/blob/e79c75a14eb20640afbcab3ee110eccdd8378720/examples/gce-to-adminsdk/README.md and it worked for my Cloud Function.

Make sure your project subnet has Private Google Access enabled and your service account has Token Creator role on *itself* (to create the Signer object).

This worked for me:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account, id_token
from google.auth import default, impersonated_credentials, iam
from google.auth.transport import requests
import functions_framework


scopes = ['your_scope']
admin_to_impersonate = your_admin

def get_impersonated_credentials():
    try:
        # Refresh the default credentials. This ensures that the information
        # about this account, notably the email, is populated.
        request = requests.Request()
        credentials.refresh(request)

        # Create an IAM signer using the default credentials.
        signer = iam.Signer(
            request,
            credentials,
            credentials.service_account_email
        )

        # Create OAuth 2.0 Service Account credentials using the IAM-based
        # signer and the bootstrap_credential's service account email. 
        # Impersonate the given subject.
        creds = service_account.Credentials(
            signer,
            credentials.service_account_email,
            token_uri,
            scopes=scopes,
            subject=admin_to_impersonate
        )

    except Exception:
        raise
    
    return creds
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).